# Adding options property while generating json schema using JSchemaGenerator

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I am using Newtonsoft's [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) schema generator and I want to generate a JSON schema and hide few fields. I know that it is possible with the use of `options` property. Here is a sample schema that uses this property.

```
{
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "options": { "hidden": true },
      "description": "First and Last name",
      "minLength": 4,
      "default": "Jeremy Dorn"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a class that is a base for the schema and I have decided to use a custom attribute on properties that I want to hide during schema generation. Then using custom GenerationProvider I want to check if the field has the attribute and if it does then add the `"options": { "hidden": true },` bit.

The problem is that `JSchema` class doesn't have the `Hidden` property (like the `JsonSchema` class had previously) nor the `Options` property.

Note: I don't want to use the `[JsonIgnore]` as I need those properties serialized in some places, but I only want them hidden while creating the schema.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Using the obsolete [`JsonSchema`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JsonSchema.htm), I can't create the schema you show in your question. Rather than `"options": { "hidden": true },` I get `"hidden": true,`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/OyB9b3.  Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing how you generated that example schema with the old `JsonSchema`?

Comment: And if I try to parse the schema shown in your question with `JsonSchema`, the `"options": { "hidden": true },` property is silently stripped out, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/vnHNxb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather long reply to @dbc which helped me to get this done. As my classes that I create the schema for are quite big and contain loads of different types inside them I couldn't get this solution to work. Few things that I noticed here. I am using `"Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="3.0.14"` and inside the custom provider the line

```
var contract = (JsonObjectContract)context.Generator.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(context.ObjectType);
```

was throwing exception as the casting to `JsonObjectContrac` was impossible since `context.Generator.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(context.ObjectType);` was returning `JsonPrimitiveContract`. I didn't want to spend too much time on resolving that therefore I went on with the code and tried to perform something like dbc did in this code:

```
foreach (var propertySchema in schema.Properties)
        {
            // Find the corresponding JsonProperty from the contract resolver.
            var jProperty = contract.Properties[propertySchema.Key];
            // Check to see if the member has HiddenAttribute set.
            if (jProperty.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(HiddenAttribute), true).Any())
                // If so add "options": { "hidden": true }
                propertySchema.Value.ExtensionData["options"] = new JObject(new JProperty("hidden", true));
        }
```

Another problem occured as `schema.Properties` was empty in most of the cases. I noticed that this custom provider was not only called once but it was called for every property that was the part of my base class for the schema and once for the base class itself (basically this provider was called hundreds of times). So I ended up just creating the schema in my class and then applying the `ExtensionData`. Therefore my provider besides doing some other logic it has the `CheckIsHidden(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context, JSchema schema)` method that does the job:

```
        public static void CheckIsHidden(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context, JSchema schema)
        {
            var hiddenAttribute = context.MemberProperty?.AttributeProvider?.GetAttributes(true)
                ?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType().Name == nameof(JsonConfigIgnoreAttribute));
            if (hiddenAttribute != null)
            {
                schema.ExtensionData["options"] = new JObject(new JProperty("hidden", true));
            }
        }
```

The comment definitely helped me with achieving this as I was mainly looking for this one specific line `schema.ExtensionData["options"] = new JObject(new JProperty("hidden", true));`. Thanks very much!

Comment: *the casting to `JsonObjectContrac` was impossible since `context.Generator.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(context.ObjectType);` was returning `JsonPrimitiveContract`* -- This should not have happened because `CanGenerateSchema` was overridden to return true only if the contract was in fact of type `JsonObjectContract`.  Did you omit the override when you copied my code?

Comment: *Another problem occured as `schema.Properties` was empty in most of the cases.* - again this should not happen as long as `CanGenerateSchema` was overridden.

Answer (score 1):

The keywords `"options": { "hidden": true }` or even `"hidden": true` do not appear to be among the [validation keywords](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html) for the current [JSON Schema specification](https://json-schema.org/specification.html) -- or any earlier version as far as I can tell.  The only keywords that seem related are `readOnly` and `writeOnly`.  From the [docs](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#annotations):

> **New in draft 7** The boolean keywords `readOnly` and `writeOnly` are typically used in an API context. `readOnly` indicates that a value should not be modified. It could be used to indicate that a `PUT` request that changes a value would result in a `400 Bad Request` response. `writeOnly` indicates that a value may be set, but will remain ***hidden***. In could be used to indicate you can set a value with a `PUT` request, but it would not be included when retrieving that record with a `GET` request.
>
> ```json
> {
>   "title": "Match anything",
>   "description": "This is a schema that matches anything.",
>   "default": "Default value",
>   "examples": [
>     "Anything",
>     4035
>   ],
>   "readOnly": true,
>   "writeOnly": false 
> }
> ```

Thus it would seem that `"options": { "hidden": true }` is some sort of custom or 3rd-party extension to the JSON Schema standard.  Json.NET schema supports such custom validation keywords through the [`JSchema.ExtensionData`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchema_ExtensionData.htm) property.  To set your hidden option in this extension data during automatic schema generation, define the following [`JSchemaGenerationProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CreateCustomProvider.htm):

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class HiddenAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}

public class HiddenOptionProvider : CustomizedProviderBase
{
    public override JSchema GetSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
    {
        var schema = base.GetSchema(context);
        // Get the JsonObjectContract for this type.
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)context.Generator.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(context.ObjectType);
        foreach (var propertySchema in schema.Properties)
        {
            // Find the corresponding JsonProperty from the contract resolver.
            var jProperty = contract.Properties[propertySchema.Key];
            // Check to see if the member has HiddenAttribute set.
            if (jProperty.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(HiddenAttribute), true).Any())
                // If so add "options": { "hidden": true }
                propertySchema.Value.ExtensionData["options"] = new JObject(new JProperty("hidden", true));
        }
        
        return schema;
    }

    public override bool CanGenerateSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context) =>
        base.CanGenerateSchema(context) && context.Generator.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(context.ObjectType) is JsonObjectContract;
}

public abstract class CustomizedProviderBase : JSchemaGenerationProvider
{
    // Base class that allows generation of a default schema which may then be subsequently customized. 
    // Note this class contains state information and so is not thread safe.
    readonly Stack<Type> currentTypes = new ();

    public override JSchema GetSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
    {
        if (CanGenerateSchema(context))
        {
            var currentType = context.ObjectType;
            try
            {
                currentTypes.Push(currentType);
                return context.Generator.Generate(currentType);
            }
            finally
            {
                currentTypes.Pop();
            }
        }
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    public override bool CanGenerateSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context) => 
        !currentTypes.TryPeek(out var t) || t != context.ObjectType;
}
```

Then define your `Person` type as follows:

```
[DisplayName("Person")]
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("name", Required = Required.DisallowNull)]
    [DefaultValue("Jeremy Dorn"), MinLength(4), System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute("First and Last name")]
    [Hidden] // Your custom attribute
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Jeremy Dorn";
}
```

And generate a schema as follows:

```
var generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
generator.GenerationProviders.Add(new HiddenOptionProvider());
var schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Person));
```

You will get the following schema, as required:

```json
{
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "description": "First and Last name",
      "options": {
        "hidden": true
      },
      "type": "string",
      "default": "Jeremy Dorn",
      "minLength": 4
    }
  }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Slz98H).

Comment: This worked perfectly. I added my own custom generator. The only difference I did was I checked to see if the `"options"` existed. If it didn't, I added them. Finally, I appended to the `"options"`. This allows me to combine multiple options together under the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Newtonsoft, but JsonSchema.Net.Generation can do this easily with the built-in `[JsonIgnore]` attribute.  This schema library is built on top of `System.Text.Json`.

I apparently need to document that this specifically is supported, but here's the rest of the [docs](https://gregsdennis.github.io/json-everything/usage/schema-generation.html) for the library.  I do have a [test (line 168)](https://www.github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything/tree/master/JsonSchema.Generation.Tests%2FSchemaGenerationTests.cs) confirming that it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I don't want to use the `[JsonIgnore]` as I need those fields serialized in some places. I have updated my original question.

Comment: Interesting use case. If you want, open an issue on my repo, so I can track it, and I'll try to add it in.  We can discuss it a bit more there too.

Comment: I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything/issues/143) for it.  I'd be happy if you joined in the discussion.

Comment: Thanks, however I cannot change the package we are using for the schema generation. Company policy ‍♀️. The use case is indeed interesting as the class that is the base for the schema has to be fully serializable because we need all of the properties for our system to work. The situation changes when we want to display the configuration for our users who do not need to know everything that is inside the config. This probably should have two different classes but thats how things are at the moment :) Anyway, thanks for your time and help

Comment: It was a good suggestion in any case, and I've added it to my library.  If you ever want to drop Newtonsoft and upgrade to System.Text.Json, that's the way to go.